# TypeError: stat() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to make server check if file exists.

The following is from server:

```py
filename = sock.recv(1024)
strfilename = b'filename'

#if file exist,
if os.path.exists(filename):
    sock.send("fEXISTS" + (os.path.getsize(strfilename)))
    clientReply = sock.recv(1024)
```

And the following is from client

```py
filename = raw_input("What file do you wish to download? -> ")

if filename != 'q':
    ssl_sock.send(filename)
```

Comment: What filename(s) are you trying your code with?

Comment: my filename input is hello.txt and ha.jpg